# Whats the most efficient way to push constant signals from combinator chips to a ring store in recroom?

Tags: rec-room

I'm trying to build up a reference to some questions I have been asking myself.

Whats the best way to push a constant number so you don't deal with constant signals messing up a ring store.

Comment: Are you wanting to only add a number to the combinator if it changes? So, for instance, if a constant signal changes from 8 to 5, the combinator will then have a store of 8+5=13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for what the wiki calls a Copy Value circuit. It copies whatever value you put into one slot when you trigger a signal. The images below are taken from the wiki. The button represents any kind of trigger signal to make the circuit copy the value. You can also use the value itself as the trigger signal, in that case the circuit will just remember the last non-zero value. This is also called Pulse to Steady in the wiki.

For more details, and maybe the kind of reference you are trying to build, visit the wiki: https://rec-room.fandom.com/wiki/Circuit_Diagrams#Copy_Value

RNG based:

[image: RNG Based Copy Value]

Ring Based:

[image: Ring Based Copy Value]